# Elixir HTTPoison no case clause matching: false error

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir, httpoison

I’m currently trying to build a simple HTTP service in Elixir that queries a web services (SOAP) API using `HTTPoison` via a proxy. This is what my code looks like:

```
defp body do
  """
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://wwww.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://wwww.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
      <ExecuteDatasetStoredProcedure>
        <securityPassword>ApiKey1234</securityPassword>
        <name>pa_sp_GetContactInfo</name>
        <parameters></parameters>
      </ExecuteDatasetStoredProcedure>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
  """
end

defp headers do
  [{"Content-Type", "text/xml"},
   {"Host", "example-api.example.com"},
   {"SOAPAction", "https://example-api.example.com/Execute/Stored/Procedure"}]
end

defp options do
  [{:proxy, "http://username:password@eu-west-static-01.quotaguard.com:9293"}, 
   {:proxy_auth, {"username", "password"}}, 
   {:ssl, [{:versions, [:'tlsv1.2']}]}]
end

def show(conn, %{"email" => email}) do
  case HTTPoison.post(api_url, body, headers, options) do
    {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{body: body}} ->
      conn |> json(%{reason: body})
    {:error, %HTTPoison.Error{reason: reason}} ->
      conn |> json(%{error: reason})
  end
end
```

However, when I run this code it returns:

```
no case clause matching: false
```

And when I check the console, I see:

```
[error] proxy error: "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n400 Bad Request: missing required Host header"
```

I’ve verified that none of the headers or options are false. For some reason it doesn’t recognise that the `Host` header is present.

Comment: Can you please show the full stack trace you are receiving when you get this error?

Comment: Would you mind to share the whole error message? Also, are you sure `proxy_url` is not `false` by any chance?

Comment: I have updated the question with some more info. It seems the error is related to lack of `Host` in the headers — although it actually is there.

Comment: Would you mind posting the real code? It would be helpful to see how get_host is being set (or called if its a function), or if you inspect the value of get_header what does it return? (i.e. is it a binary value)

Comment: @TheBrofessor I have updated the above with proper with proper values in place for you.